# The usage of "myself" - possessive

Tags: grammar, possessives

I was reading through some of the posts regarding reference to something "possessed" by more than one person, and I can't seem to find an agreement of the usage of *of myself*.

Is it correct to say the following?

> The efforts of myself and my ilk.

I understand that something like:

> The efforts of my ilk and I

is incorrect, but I'm not sure about the former. I know it's neither an intensive or reflexive use, so I assume that it is incorrect, but any clarification in this regard would be appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Edit: While the usage of "myself" has been adequately explained elsewhere, I just wanted clarification for this particular usage. I've heard it used frequently, but I couldn't find a grammatical basis for it. I apologise for the lack of clarity.

Comment: I've read that page. It's more of a general question about reflexives, than of this particular usage/phrase.

Comment: As the question stands, it is about reflexives, and that question covers this case. If your question is about something else, make your case.

Comment: Sorry. I removed the reflexives tag for clarity. I was just curious about this particular phrase.

Comment: I retracted my close vote. There are still 3 votes pending, and it only takes 5 to close, so the question may still get closed.

Answer (score 0):

> The efforts of myself and my ilk.

The word 'myself' is chiefly reflexive. Thus we could say 'When I was young, I had a perception of myself as indestructible.'

'a perception of myself' works and sounds right reflexively.

'an effort of myself' doesn't work as a reflexive.

> The efforts of my ilk and I

That is ungrammatical. You would not say 'the efforts of I', you would say 'my efforts' or 'the efforts of me'.

I suggest

*The efforts of my ilk and me*

or

**My answer**

*The efforts of me and my ilk*

I prefer the latter because the phrase 'my ilk' then refers back to the already mentioned 'me'.

**Note**

When we say 'of John and me', we place John first as a conventional mark of respect. However, although 'ilk' may refer to people, it isn't a person so we don't have to place it first.

Comment: That and intensive

Comment: Maybe it's a regional thing, but "the effort of me" sounds odd. I can't seem to find much on its usage. It seems grammatically correct, but I've never heard it until now.

Comment: In that case, I suggest the longer phrase, '*my efforts and those of my ilk*'